# Discord.py create an invite link to join a voice channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I want my discord bot to create an invite link to join the voice channel that the person who called the command is in.

```
@client.command()
async def voiceinvite(ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice:
        await ctx.send(ctx.message.author.voice.create_invite(max_age=120, max_uses=10))
    else:
        await ctx.send("Join a voice channel")
```

I've tried this but there's an error about references.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) your question to include the error.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should include the error message you got so we can figure out what is wrong

But as for the question:

The problem here is that you're trying to call `create_invite()` on a `VoiceState` object. You need to call it on a `VoiceChannel` object as documented in the docs.

The solution would be:

```
@client.command()
async def voiceinvite(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    if channel:
        invite = channel.create_invite(max_age=120, max_uses=10)
        await ctx.send(invite)
    else:
        await ctx.send("Join a voice channel")
```

[API Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=create_invite#discord.VoiceChannel.create_invite)

Next time, **Please include the error when there is one.** It helps people answer questions as errors have information about the problem and sometimes even the solution itself!